# Is it possible to gzip or compress .otf (Open Type Face) files?

Tags: apache, fonts, compression, css, embedded-fonts

When using CSS3 and custom fonts, the client needs to download .oft or .ttf files. These files can be >50K. Can these files be compressed? How? Assuming Apache web server.

I am looking for a compression technique or an Apache configuration. Any ideas will help because downloading +50K files should be prevented.

Comment: Would probably fit better in superuser.com or serverfault.com

Comment: I asked the question here because, frankly, I expect the smartest people at this site. Further, since I am the developer for my particular project, I will have to write code or make apache configurations to solve this programming related problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.ttf files compress quite well (analysis with hex editor shows a lot of 0x00's and simple zipping reduces their size to 50% or even less of original size - at least fonts I checked), so I think any compression script would do the trick and I think same rule applies oft files as well.